# how to change login button to logout after the user login PHP

Tags: php, authentication, if-statement, button, logout

My login button maintains login after the user logged in. The code below is what I tried.

```
<?php 
        //session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])) {
            echo' <a href="logout.php"><input id="btnlogout" 
type="button" value="LOGOUT" class="log" /></a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="login.php"><input id="btnlogin" 
type="button" value="LOGIN" class="log" /></a>';
            echo '<a href="register.php"><input id="btnregistser" 
type="button" value="Register" class="reg" /></a>';
        }
        ?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']);
session_destroy();
echo "You have logout successfully";
header("refresh:2;url=homepage.php");
?>
```

check.php (to check on homepage *1st php* data)

```
if ($username==$row['username'] && $password==$row['password']){
        session_start();
        //$_SESSION['username']=$username;
        $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = true;
    echo "You have logged in successfully.";
    header("refresh:2;url=homepage.php");
    break;
    }
    else{   
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    header("Location:fail.php");
    }
        }
```

I expect the button can change to logout button but it doesn't work.

Comment: u r missing the condition in the if statement https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#:~:text=if%20(expr)%0A%20%20statement

Comment: `<input>` inside `<a>` makes no sense

Comment: a logout button should be a POST request, with `<a>` u r making a GET request, use a `<form>` + method post instead

Comment: is  ```$_SESSION['user_logged_in']``` only getting set on login.php?

Comment: @LucasdeRijke yes, as shown, right?

Comment: than it should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this

```
<?php 
//session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])) {
    echo' <a href="logout.php"><input id="btnlogout" type="button" value="LOGOUT" class="log" /></a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="login.php"><input id="btnlogin" type="button" value="LOGIN" class="log" /></a>';
    echo '<a href="register.php"><input id="btnregistser" type="button" value="Register" class="reg" /></a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: it shows 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "}", expecting "," or ";" in } else { line.

Comment: edited the code, should be fine now.

Comment: it works now but ermmmmmm after i log out, it shows me logout

Comment: Do you clear the session when you logout? use ```unset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']);``` after logout script.

Comment: yes. 
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user_logged_in']);
echo "You have logout successfully";
header("refresh:2;url=homepage.php");
?>

Comment: I think I fixed it. Ill change the answer.

Comment: its better, it show login first but after login successfully, it remain same thing.

Comment: i have a check.php which to check the username and password.

if ($username==$row['username'] && $password==$row['password']){
         session_start();
         //$_SESSION['username']=$username;
   $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = true;
  echo "You have logged in successfully.";
  header("refresh:2;url=homepage.php");
  break;
  }
  else{   
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['username']=$username;
  header("Location:fail.php");
  }
            }

Comment: try ```var_dump($_SESSION['user_logged_in']);``` on you homepage and look if it is set.

Comment: seems like not work

Comment: i edit my question to show all my code for now